# CSS code not working inside form

Tags: html, css

So I have this form, and inside it's got a div with a paragraph. The paragraph belongs to the class "create-account". But inside create-account in my CSS, where I set the font-size and font-style. The code doesn't affect my paragraph. And I literally have no clue why. Any help would is greatly appreciated.

```css
.create-account {
  font-size: 24;
  font-style: arial;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <p class="create-account">Create your account here</p>
    <hr/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: is the css in your html file? if it is it needs to be enclosed with <style></style>

Comment: @schylake, It needs to be enclosed with `style` tags. Not `script` tags. That is for Javascript.

Comment: you are right need more coffee fixed

Comment: the font size is `24`, but `24` what? point? pixels? em? rem? or one of another thousand possible sizing options? That part is required or else the browser doesn't know what you want. And it won't make a guess.

Comment: "inside form" is a massive red herring. Your CSS is simply wrong. Use a validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: The CSS is in a separate file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing some units to your `font-size` property, and you also would need to use `font-family` instead of `font-style`

```
.create-account {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

The font won't apply because you set it on `font-style`. You need to use `font-family: arial;`